# Push replicas from master to slave in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have a network topology where the master serves as a read/write database in one network, and has several slaves in different networks that are read-only for security reasons. Due to firewall restrictions, the slaves cannot establish a connection to the network the master resides in.

Is there a mechanism that allows the master to replicate itself to the slaves by only pushing out to the slaves? After reading a bit about replication in psql, it seems that the slaves need network access to the master.

Comment: How would the slaves get data from the master if they don't have network access to it?

Comment: @CalZ The slaves cannot establish connections from where they are, but the master can establish connections with the slaves.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate. Any type of network connection? Can they SSH to one another? Ship files? Can you do this? https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

Comment: I could probably do whatever type I want in that direction.

Answer (score 3):

No,there is no mechanism where a master will find out slaves waiting for replication.Slave to master connection is a necessary requirement as slave needs to authenticate to master.
If you are sure the connection is not getting established due to a restricting firewall then you need to configure your firewall to allow connection.Otherwise,you need to allow slaves' ip in pg_hba.conf on master server.

Comment: What about setting the archive_command to be rsync over to the slaves, and then use the restore_command on the same path where the archives where placed? 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/continuous-archiving.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change your firewall policy, perhaps you could archive your WALs in another machine (with a great backup tool as barman or backrest) and your replicas should be able to retrieve the WALs from that backup machine (but that will make your replication lag bigger).